# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word + MS Word Starter

Tags: c#

I have an application that extracts information from a focused application.
this works fine, i can extracts information if the focused application is MS Word 2003,2007 and 2010, my problem comes in MS Word 2010 starter.
i have this code to extract data from the current ms word (in focused)

```
var appObj = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
Document activeDocument = appObj.ActiveDocument;
Name = activeDocument.Name;
```

my Question is. Does `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` support Starter editions?
if not, can you give me any ways to extract data from that MS Word Starter?
any help will be appreciated. 
thanks

Comment: I think you want to use the [Primary Interop Assemblies](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508). You can install these and use the Interop libraries without needing to install Office.

Comment: it is already installed. infact i can already use it.and it works fine with normal version of office(2003,2007 and 2010) The problem is when using the Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application"); it returns a null value when MS Word Starter is in focused.

Comment: This is a limitation of MS Word Starter.  You will be unable to use the Interop COM library with that version of Word.  This fact is well documented.